# Count records, different tables, group by, timestamp, in interevals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL example (there's more to it, just additional queries on tables, same structure) which gives me a list of tables and those that the UpdatedOn field is a unique value, denoting an "individual" edit was performed, as opposed to a edit with an update statment changing multiple records with the same timestamp.  This SQL works great.  However, I want to go further.  I want to get the count represented by months, and preferabely, by year, so the results grow and accumulate.  Here's my SQL:

```
select 'BuriedSplice' as [Table], count(*) as Changes from BuriedSplice where UpdatedOn in 
  (select UpdatedOn from BuriedSplice group by UpdatedOn having count(*) = 1)
    union
select 'CableCoil' as [Table], count(*) as Changes from CableCoil where UpdatedOn in 
  (select UpdatedOn from CableCoil group by UpdatedOn having count(*) = 1)
```

The results are:

```
Table           Changes
BuriedSplice    53
CableCoil       14
```

What I want to see is something like:

```
Table           1/2013 Changes  2/2013 Changes  3/2013 Changes
BuriedSplice    12              17              24 
CableCoil       4               3               7
```

Or like:

```
January 2013
Table           Changes
BuriedSplice    12 
CableCoil       4

February 2013
Table           Changes
BuriedSplice    17 
CableCoil       3

March 2013
Table           Changes
BuriedSplice    24 
CableCoil       7
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest a slightly different format, with the following headings:

```
Year   Month    BuriedSpice    CableCoil
```

The reason is that year/month could have many rows.  But the tables going into the query -- even if more than 2 -- are fixed.  All SQL queries have a fixed number of columns, so this format makes sense.

The following takes this approach using a `union all` query:

```
select yr, mon, sum(BuriedSpice) as BuriedSplice, sum(CableCoil) as CableCoil
from ((select year(UpdatedOn) as yr, month(UpdatedOn) as mon, count(*) as BuriedSplice, 0 as CableCoil
       from (select UpdatedOn
             from BuriedSplice
             group by UpdatedOn
             having count(*) = 1
            ) bs
       group by year(UpdatedOn), month(UpdatedOn)
      ) union all
      (select year(UpdatedOn) as yr, month(UpdatedOn) as mon, 0, count(*)
       from (select UpdatedOn
             from CableCoil
             group by UpdatedOn
             having count(*) = 1
            ) cc
       group by year(UpdatedOn), month(UpdatedOn)
      )
     ) t
group by yr, mon
```

Comment: What's this about buried spice?!?!? You've been reading too much of Frank Herbert's *Dune*. :) :)

Comment: Buried Splice, as in splicing Cable.  Although I do like the movie Dune

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I think this is a better approach than what I had.  I tried the SQL you provided (fixed the first sum to add the l missing from BuriedSpice) and got the following error:  "SQL Server Database Error: Column 'bs.UpdatedOn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  This worked for me and I was able to expand it to cover about 25 different tables.  I couldn't vote up your answer because I don't have enough reputation points :-(